# How to configure Windows 11 Configuration Designer from ADK to launch executable jar file

Tags: java, windows, jar, configuration, kiosk-mode

My Goal is to configure Windows 11 Configuration Designer from ADK to launch an executable jar file which is located in `C:\MyExecutableJarFolder\executableJarFile.jar`

I downloaded the Windows Imaging and Configuration Designer app and dependencies from adk for Windows 11

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/get-started/adk-install#download-the-adk-for-windows-11-version-22h2

With the intent to use it to set up a provisioning package so that I can configure my machine to run in a brand friendly kiosk mode (where windows startup logo and login screens are never seen). The kiosk mode which is enabled by the Configuration Designer achieves the brand friendly auto login nicely but it never launches the jar.

I filled in all the required settings in Configuration Designer for

`Setup device` (I added a 15 character Device Name),

`Set up network` (I set to Off),

`Account managment` (I set to local admin),

`Add applications` (I left blank),

`Add certificate` (I left blank), and under

`Configure kiosk account and app` (I created a "Kiosk" user account with password and auto sign in enabled) and under

`Configure the kiosk mode app` > `Username` = `Kiosk` > `App type` = `Classic Windows App` > `Enter either the full path to the app or a filename in the Path environment variable` = `C:\MyExecutableJarFolder\executableJarFile.jar`

`Configure kiosk common settings` > `Set tablet mode` > `No`

`Customize user experience` > `Yes` > `Configure Welcome Screen buttons` > `1` > `Disable status messages during startup, signin, and shut down` > `1`

`Hide Welcome screen when auto sign in is enabled` > `yes`

`Disable lock screen` > `yes`

`Configure Power settings` > `yes`

`Turn off screen timeout` > `yes` > `turn off sleep timeout` > `yes`

The provisioning package installs correctly and automatically logs in but does not launch the executable jar in the file path (and the file path is correct). I then tried to point the configuration manager to a batch file instead (which when double clicked does actually launch the jar) and that still did not work.

I also tried to move the batch file to `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup` and this did not work either. Curiosly when I exit kiosk mode through `ctrl + alt + delete > run new task > explorer.exe` the jar does launch when the batch file is in this directory.

The goal is to launch the executable jar in kiosk mode.

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: I created a ticket for Microsoft Support regarding the issue and was told it is a bug they may fix in the future.... I am hoping for ideas on a workaround, so that I can trigger my jar to launch in kiosk mode.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a work around (Although it is not Ideal)

I still use the provisioning package which is generated by Windows 11 Configuration Designer from ADK 22h2 to ensure that Windows boots in brand friendly kiosk mode but I then also schedule a task to run the jar on login for the kiosk user:

`Open Start menu > Task Scheduler > ENTER > Action > Create Task > Change User or Group > select the Kiosk User Account to run the task > Select "Run only when user is logged on" > Task profile > Windows 10 > Triggers > New > "Begin the task" menu > At log on > Select Specific user > OK > Actions tab > Browse > locate executable jar at path C:\myJarFolder\myJarFile.jar > OK > Log on` with the selected kiosk mode user to test.

Reference: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/b44f3310-774d-48a4-ad8f-3ec54a7c08b9/prevent-windows-explorer-from-starting?forum=w7itprogeneral